# Bootstrap style button group on ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have these 3 buttons on my ASP.NET GridView leftmost column.

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="E" CommandName="EditTimeRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-default" >
<ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-default" />
<ItemStyle Width="5%" />
</asp:ButtonField>

<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="C" CommandName="CopyTimeRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-default" >
<ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-default" />
<ItemStyle Width="5%" />
</asp:ButtonField>

<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="D" CommandName="DeleteTimeRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-default" >
<ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-default" />
<ItemStyle Width="5%" />
</asp:ButtonField>
```

I would like to group these together like dropdown menus mixed with a series of buttons.
I had also thought about doing this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Action
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="EditRow">Edit</button>
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="CopyRow">Copy</button>
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="DeleteRow">Delete</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

but then I would lose the ASP grid and button events.

I would rather use the ASP.NET button controls because it is easier to use and manipulate the grid and wire up to my back end code.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                <asp:Button Text="Edit" CssClass="dropdown-item" CommandName="EditTimeRecord" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button Text="Copy" CssClass="dropdown-item" CommandName="CopyTimeRecord" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button Text="Delete" CssClass="dropdown-item" CommandName="DeleteTimeRecord" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```